# Is the pressure of a gas proportional with the concentration of a gas?

Tags: concentration, pressure

Is the pressure of a gas proportional with the concentration of a gas?

Because you can also use the pressure instead of the concentration in the  equilibrium condition.

Comment: What do you call the "concentration" of a gas ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon mol/l?

Comment: I'm feeling generous: use the ideal gas law.

Comment: Assuming it follows $PV=nRT$, then if the temperature is fixed then indeed it's proportional to $n/V$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your gas follows the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law), you have $PV=nRT$. Setting $c=\frac nV$ yields $P(c,T)=cRT$.

If the temperature is fixed, then $P(c)=(RT)c$ indeed tells us that **the pressure of a gas is proportional to its concentration**.